# How to convert my wireless keyboard Bluetooth dongle as universal bluetooth dongle?

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, bluetooth, dongle

So I have an old Logitech wireless keyboard which is still working perfectly fine. I was wondering if I could use its bluetooth dongle in order to connect my bluetooth speakers(different brand) to my computer? Is this something possible at all? If so I'd be happy if I could get a hint or some writeups on that.

Answer (score 15):

Try this solution found at forums.logitech.com  It worked for me. The issue seems to be that the Logitech dongle is using HID mode and needs to be in HCI mode to work with headphones.

I know this is an old thread, but I'm adding this in case anyone else is looking for a solution to this problem.

When I first got my diNovo Edge, I found and tried the solution here.  Unfortunately, I also discovered that following these instructions locks the dongle in Bluetooth mode.  That is, even when you power up your system, the dongle is in BT mode!

That presented a big problem for me, because I could no longer get into BIOS!  (Note: if anyone who sees this knows of a way to use the instructions here to put the dongle in BT mode and retain the ability to get into BIOS, please share it!)

Anyway, I found an alternate solution, two actually!

The first, which is the one I use, is found [here](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=5).  This guy wrote a small program, called ***LHid2Hci***, which works perfectly.  All you do is download the binary and place a shortcut to it in your Startup folder.  The binary takes two command line options, the VID&PID values of the Bluetooth dongle.  (The instructions are all there.)

The program does exactly what the name says, it converts the Logitech Bluetooth dongle from HID (USB) to HCI (Bluetooth) mode!  It's activated when you log in, and voila! you have your Bluetooth dongle, with which you can pair any other device.  (I have a Microsoft Bluetooth number pad and a Bluetooth stereo headset.)

The way in which this solution is different is that, when your system reboots, the dongle goes back into HID mode, meaning that your keyboard is immediately connected, and you can get into BIOS!

That's also why the command to run this program has to be in the Startup folder.  It has to run every time a user logs in.

The second solution I mentioned is the ***LBTService***, search on Google.

This is a service that supposedly does the exact same thing as LHid2Hci, but as a service instead of a startup program.

I haven't used this one, since I found the former solution first, however I've seen a lot of people who are using it successfully, so I figured I should mention it.

Comment: Or see here (pretty informative and very deep insights): http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=5

Cannot create a new post, unfortunately....

Comment: I know this is old, but I have tried this, I can get to "Converted 1 HID devices to native HCI mode." but that is about as far as I can get, it never shows up as a bt device. Any insight to this? I am using a unifying receiver.

Answer (score 11):

Are you sure the dongle is actually a Bluetooth dongle? Logitech is pretty big on their [Unifying receivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_Unifying_receiver), which are used to connect up to six Logitech devices using similar (but incompatible) technology to Bluetooth.

The unifying receivers tend to be marked with a 'red star' type logo, though my one has the text '1000Hz' printed on it instead because it came with a 'high performance' mouse.

[image: Logitech Unifying Receiver, from the Wiki]

If it is one of these propriety dongles, you won't be able to re-purpose it as a generic Bluetooth reciever.

If your receiver, however, has the blue bluetooth logo on it, it should already be available within Windows as a generic Bluetooth adapter.

Answer (score 6):

I recently stumbled upon this when I was trying to find out the answer to a similar question using my Logitech diNovo Mini Bluetooth dongle. The diNovo mini definitely uses Bluetooth so I was sure the USB dongle was a Bluetooth one. The included dongle has two modes that it operates in, an embedded mode and a Bluetooth mode. It's set to embedded mode by default which allows you to connect to the Logitech device without having to do the pairing process. To switch it to Bluetooth mode you have to do the following:

1. Unplug the dongle from your computer
2. Press and hold the connect button on the dongle while plugging it into your computer. If you are using Windows then you will probably see a drivers update tooltip showing that it is installing a Bluetooth device.

Once you do this, you can now pair a Bluetooth device directly from Windows by simply going to your taskbar's Bluetooth icon.

Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/to-connect-s2-to-dinovo-mini-bluetooth-t1476164

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy... I had an old Logitech BT dongle in a drawer and now I use it for my BT headset. When I googled it I was pretty sure I would have to hack drivers or something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(I'm no expert. Anyone, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.)

It is possible in general, although a Bluetooth dongle may support only a subset of Bluetooth profiles. I think keyboards operate on HID profile, while speakers require A2DP. So you may or may not be able to use speakers with your specific dongle, depending on what profiles it supports. You should try to pair your speakers with the dongle in the same way you have paired your keyboard and in the same way you have paired your speakers elsewhere. Have in mind that successful pairing may happen even if the dongle lacks support for required profile.

You have paired your keyboard at least once? Or haven't you?

In case you never had to pair your keyboard with the dongle, there comes another issue: are you sure you've got Bluetooth keyboard, not a simple wireless one? It's good if you are sure, but certainly there are users out there who do not know the difference, so let me explain for them.

As far as I know, vast majority of wireless keyboards and mice uses non-bluetooth (vendor specific, I think) protocols to communicate with their dongles. The reasons are: lower power consumption and simplicity. Such a set works "out of the box", the keyboard knows nothing about relatively complex Bluetooth, pairing etc. The host may also know nothing about Bluetooth, USB support is enough. In addition there is no need for two-way communication: keyboard works as sender only, dongle as receiver; still, Bluetooth requires two-way communication even with keyboard or mouse. That's why Bluetooth devices are more expensive than their non-bluetooth counterparts.

Bluetooth or not -- how to tell? Bluetooth keyboard should have Bluetooth symbol on it and a button allowing it to pair with something other than attached dongle (example: with a laptop having internal Bluetooth adapter). In fact there is often no dongle in set. Bluetooth dongle reports to operating system as Bluetooth radio, while non-bluetooth keyboard dongle is recognized directly as a keyboard (HID device) connected to USB just like any wired USB keyboard. If your keyboard and dongle are Bluetooth devices, you have to pair them in every operating system you connect the dongle to, because Bluetooth keyboard (and any other Bluetooth device) pairs with the operating system via dongle, not with the dongle only. If given set works just by plugging the dongle, then it's not Bluetooth.

In case you cannot tell whether you've got Bluetooth or non-bluetooth keyboard, name its model here so we could figure it out. If it is Bluetooth one and you need more help pairing speakers, I need to know your operating system before I guide you further.