# use keyboard wireless receiver to pair with Xbox 360 controller

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, xbox360

I've got an old "[Logitech Cordless Desktop S520 Keyboard and Mouse](http://support.logitech.com/en_gb/product/cordless-desktop-s520)". It comes with a wireless receiver.

Is it possible to use that Logitech receiver to pair up with a wireless xbox 360 controller?
And use it with a RaspberryPi (running retropie)?

If not. What are my options?

1. Buy any Bluetooth receiver.
2. Buy a receiver specific to xbox360 controllers.

Comment: why the downvote genius?

Comment: here's a simmilar question so...why the downvote?
http://superuser.com/questions/895531/how-to-convert-my-wireless-keyboard-bluetooth-dongle-as-universal-bluetooth-dong

Comment: So basically...the answer should have been:
It's not possible because the Logitech receiver is either an IR or radio...not bluetooth.
but that downvote was *really* usefull.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Logitech receiver will not be able to communicate with the controller.

You'd need to go with option 2 - buy a wireless USB receiver for the controller and plug that into the Pi.

Comment: Thanks for that.
But...if the wii controller works with a regular Bluetooth usb dongle...why wouldn't that work for the xbox360 controller?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bO5-FjLe5xE

Comment: or is it the case the Logitech receiver is an IR receiver as opposed to a Bluetooth one?

Comment: The problem is that the Xbox wireless controller doesn't use Bluetooth or IR. It uses a proprietary radio protocol that only works with the dongle they sell for the purpose.